# how do i log into my computer using ubuntu

Tags: boot, flash, drive

I set up external flash drive to run ubuntu. How do I get it to work and not load windows XP?

Comment: Change boot priority in the BIOS to USB.

Comment: Like Mitch said in the previous comment or you can look for your **boot menu** default key used by BIOS (it can be F12 or F10 or other), and press that key each time you want to boot from USB instead of HDD or CD/DVD-ROM. There should be some notifications on your screen when you start-up your PC telling you which keys are available for entering BIOS or for getting to the boot screen.

Comment: How do I change the BIOS?

Comment: Windows XP comes up first without any notification. Ok I think I can try to use the F12 key. Thanks!

Comment: Now I get "error reading sector" when I try to log in using the usb flash drive.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain how you made the usb drive.

Comment: I used the usb installer, downloaded ubuntu, and now have it on a flash drive. Installed flash drive into hard drive, hit F12 and changed "Hard-Disk Drive" to use Usb even though it says "Usb not installed".

Comment: What USB crator doid you use?

Comment: Used USB installer and Ubuntu. The only boot sequence I have is either C drive or IDE CD-Rom. Does that mean I can't use a flash drive?

Comment: Used USB installer and Ubuntu. The only boot sequence I have is either C drive or IDE CD-Rom. Does that mean I can't use a flash drive? Hard Disk Drive sequence is either "System BIOS boot devices" or "USB device (not installed)".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go into your BIOS at startup and select which drive to bout off of. It varies widely from model to model but typically if you press F10 or F12 when you see the computer manufacture's logo the BIOS should pop up.

From here your can use the arrow keys to navigate to "boot options" (or something similarly named) where you can select the appropriate drive.